# Bootstrap 3: font family within a glyphicon span

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Twitter Bootstrap 3, given this glyphicon span:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">&nbsp;Home</span>
```

the word 'Home' is rendered in standard sans serif instead of the font of the parent tag.

How can I assign an arbitrary font family to the text inside the span, and still render the icon correctly?

Of course I could move the text outside of the span, but then the `&nbsp;` would not be honored, would it? Regardless, from a semantic standpoint it would seem reasonable to keep the text described by the icon inside the span.

Here's an example:

[image]

That's how Chrome renders the following:

```
<h1>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>&nbsp;Scoring
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</span>
</h1>
```

The first span is how I want it to look, but is semantically wrong (IMOHO), while the second looks just wrong.

Comment: As an aside, you should use CSS for the padding between the icon and the text, not `&nbsp;`. We use `span.glyphicon {margin-right: 10px}` in our base CSS (on the assumption that we generally put icons before text).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the icons are inserted using the `:before` pseudo-element you can make it so that the glyphicon font only applies to that instead of the actual element:

```
.glyphicon {
    font-family: inherit;
}
.glyphicon:before{
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/28HcG/)**

Comment: 5 years later and this is still helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> home</span>
```

**[image]**

Comment: The word 'Home' is still rendered in generic sans serif, instead of inheriting the enclosing tag's font family.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most semantic solution, but it is super easy and works.

Wrap the whole darn thing in a span with `nowrap`.

#### HTML

```
<span class="nobr">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>&nbsp;Scoring
</span>
```

#### CSS

```
.nobr {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `<nobr>` HTML tag.  Not officially supported.